# Why Bytes Per Physical Sector : <Not Supported>

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, windows-backup, fsutil

I'm trying to fight with mysterious Windows backup error "Volume larger than 2TB can be protected". I can be seen in internet but no solution.

Users give advice to check with fsutil tool.
Here are results:

System SSD disk C:

```
Bytes Per Sector  :               512 
Bytes Per Physical Sector :    512     
Bytes Per Cluster :               4096 
Bytes Per FileRecord Segment    : 1024 
Clusters Per FileRecord Segment : 0
```

Any other HDD (3 devices):

```
 Bytes Per Sector  :               512
 Bytes Per Physical Sector :       <Not Supported>
 Bytes Per Cluster :               4096
 Bytes Per FileRecord Segment    : 1024
```

Question is: WHY Physical Sector :  Not Supported ?

Answer (score 2):

If the “Byte Per Physical Sector” field displays “Not Supported” then either the storage driver does not support IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, or there was an error in retrieving the info.

Source:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848035%28v=vs.85%29.aspx